# Angular2 css file encapsulation

Tags: html, css, angular, dashboard

I know they have many and many subject about this but i don't understand :/

Today, i want to integer the Material Dashboard of Creative Tim : https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-angular2

But. This tools use a file css with the same name of class as bootstrap use. And I use bootstrap.

How to separate the two css files So that there is no conflict ?

Thx in advance !

Comment: What do you need bootstrap for if you have angular material?

Comment: I need bootstrap for ngb-bootstrap and PrimeNg !

Comment: I build an application with a calendar and i want an Admin Dashboard too.

Comment: Put them in different directories, although they probably already are.

Comment: Mhmmm...They are already separate :/